# How to include DatePicker textbox inside gridview?

Tags: asp.net

I have used Asp.net `GridView` and of course i have bounded it with my own, I have used the following code to select the table from DB and read all data into `Gridview`:

```
  protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        DataTable dt = DataProvider.ExecuteDataTable("[dbo].[Get_LastInsertedRowHowzeEducation_SP]", CommandType.StoredProcedure); 
        GridView1.DataSource = dt; 
        GridView1.DataBind(); 
    }
```

one of it's column related to BirthDate and I have designed a `Jquery` `DatePicker` `TextBox` so I would like to include it inside one of `Gridview` column as a `TextBox` and remove the default `GridView` `TextBox`.So, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a template column inside your `GridView` and then hook up the JQuery datepicker:

Here's the result:

[image]

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvpicker" AutoGenerateEditButton="true" OnRowEditing="gvpicker_RowEditing">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("job_desc") %>' runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("job_desc") %>' ID="myDatePicker" CssClass="myDatePickerClass" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<script>
    $(function () {
        var $gv = $("table[id$=gvpicker]");
        var $rows = $("> tbody > tr:not(:has(th, table))", $gv);
        var $inputs = $(".myDatePickerClass", $rows);

        $rows.css("background-color", "yellow");

        $inputs.datepicker();
    });
</script>

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            this.BindGrid();
        }
    }

    protected void gvpicker_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        this.gvpicker.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        this.BindGrid();
    }
```

Now if you have a custom control, just replace

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("job_desc") %>' ID="myDatePicker" CssClass="myDatePickerClass" />
```

For your custom control

In a template section inside a data-bound control you can place any control you like

Comment: I think i couldn't convey truely my mean to you , i meaned if i insert update button inside gridview , the datepicked textbox to be existed instead of previous gridview textbox.

Comment: I'd love to help u but I didn't understand your English

Comment: Ok.let me explain better. in girdview,when i press the update button some textbox will be visible, one of it's textbox is for datetime which is in default and comes from DB, but i want to change this simple textbox to a textbox jquery(which i have made, that user when click on textbox the datepicker appears and can choose special date)and include it inside gridview. thak you so much

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the column by hand as a `TemplateField`. 
For instance http://www.vkinfotek.com/gridview/templatefields-in-gridview.html

Answer (score 0):

Seems, jQuery library and jQuery UI library are to your project.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.dummy').datepicker();
  });
</script>
```

```html
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%">
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DOJ">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" class="dummy"></asp:TextBox>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

There is no implemention of the class "dummy" in css. It is just a dummy class. We use it to identify those textboxes which are inside Gridview and we want jQuery to generate datepicker over there.

Answer (score 0):

here try this works fine

```
<script src="js/jsDatepicker/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <%--<script src="js/jsDatepicker/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>--%>
    <link href="js/jsDatepicker/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/jsDatepicker/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(".cal").datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                yearRange: "1990:2100"
            });
        });
    </script>


<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4"   placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" CssClass="form-control cal" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="TextBox4" Display="Dynamic" runat="server" />
```

Comment: u might need the js files